# Calling multiple FB Graph API requests in codeigniter

Tags: facebook, api, codeigniter

I'm working a Facebook login functionality which works smoothly, however I tried to Google this but couldn't find anything that I was looking for.

I need to get user profile pictures, interests, likes, books, movies, music. Code below is my controller which works fine.

> class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
>
> public function __construct()   {       parent::__construct();
>
> }
>     public function index()     {
>
> ```
>     $fb_config = array(
>         'appId'  => '550765875685678567',
>         'secret' => 'e03771716c87658765843535ac38'
>     );
>
>     $this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);
>
>     $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
>
>     if ($user) {
>         try {
>             $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
>
>         } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
>             $user = null;
>         }
>     }
>
>     if ($user) {
>         $data['logout_url'] = $this->facebook
>             ->getLogoutUrl();
>     } else {
>         $data['login_url'] = $this->facebook
>             ->getLoginUrl($params = array('scope' => "email,user_birthday,
> ```
>
> user_likes, >user_interests, user_location,
>   read_friendlists, user_checkins, 
>   user_religion_politics, user_photos,
>   user_likes, user_hometown, user_about_me"));
>           }
>
> ```
>     $this->load->view('welcome',$data);
> }
> ```
>
> }

Now if I wanted to run

> ```
>  $albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');
> ```

in same function, how would I achieve this? or how can I run multiple api calls here and include it in my $data['user_profile']?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run as many API calls as you would like in sequential order and have them go into your data array.  For example:

```
$data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
$data['user_albums'] = $this->facebook->api('/me/albums');
```

Multiple calls won't cause any problems.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help